# mongodb counting document pairs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's imagine I have MongoDB collection with elements of such type:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "id1", 
    "from" : "Tom", 
    "to" : "Bill"
},
{ 
    "_id" : "id2", 
    "from" : "Jack", 
    "to" : "Tom"
},
{ 
    "_id" : "id3", 
    "from" : "Jack", 
    "to" : "Tom"
},
{ 
    "_id" : "id4", 
    "user" : "Tom", 
    "to" : "Jack"
},
{ 
    "_id" : "id4", 
    "user" : "Tom", 
    "to" : "Bill"
},
{ 
    "_id" : "id5", 
    "user" : "Bill", 
    "to" : "Jack"
}
```

Think about it like an emails. How can I aggregate such collection to find out which pair communicate the most? The thing is that we should count mails not only from A to B, but from B to A too.

Thanks a million!

Comment: Whats the difference between user / from / to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you always have `from` and `to` fields. Then you can $project your data to an ordered array of `participants`and then $group by such array:

```
db.mails.aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        participants: {
         $cond: { 
            if: { $gte: [ "$from", "$to" ] }, 
            then: [ "$to", "$from" ], 
            else: [ "$from", "$to" ] }
       }
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$participants",
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
},
{
    $sort: { "count" : -1 }
}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You may generate a unique key for each pair by combining their usernames, then you can use a hashtable to count:

```
  const hash = {};

  for(let { from, to, user} of input){
    from = from || user;
    if(from < to)
      ([from, to] = [to, from]);

    const key = from + "©" + to;

    hash[key] = (hash[key] || 0) + 1;
}
```

Now weve got the counted data. The only thing we need to do now is to iterate over the hash and find the biggest count:

```
 let result = null, count = - Infinity;

 for(let pair in hash){
   if(hash[pair] > count){
    count = hash[pair];
    result = pair;
   }
}
```